# gcc inline asm statement gets optimized away - wrong constraints?

Tags: c, gcc, constraints, inline-assembly, compiler-bug

I'm having trouble with a gcc inline asm statement; gcc seems to think the result is a constant (which it isn't) and optimizes the statement away. I *think* I am using the operand constraints correctly, but would like a second opinion on the matter. If the problem is not in my use of constraints, I'll try to isolate a test case for a gcc bug report, but that may be difficult as even subtle changes in the surrounding code cause the problem to disappear.

The inline asm in question is

```
static inline void
ularith_div_2ul_ul_ul_r (unsigned long *r, unsigned long a1,
                 const unsigned long a2, const unsigned long b)
{
  ASSERT(a2 < b); /* Or there will be quotient overflow */
  __asm__(
            "# ularith_div_2ul_ul_ul_r: divq %0 %1 %2 %3\n\t"
            "divq %3"
            : "+a" (a1), "=d" (*r)
            : "1" (a2), "rm" (b)
            : "cc");
}
```

which is a pretty run-of-the-mill remainder of a two-word dividend by a one-word divisor. Note that the high word of the input, a2, and the remainder output, *r, are tied to the same register %rdx by the "1" constraint.

From the surrounding code, `ularith_div_2ul_ul_ul_r()` gets effectively called as if by

```
if (s == 1)
  modpp[0].one = 0;
else
  ularith_div_2ul_ul_ul_r(&modpp[0].one, 0UL, 1UL, s);
```

so the high word of the input, a2, is the constant 1UL.
The resulting asm output of gcc -S -fverbose_asm looks like:

```
(earlier:)
        xorl    %r8d, %r8d      # cstore.863
(then:)
        cmpq    $1, -208(%rbp)  #, %sfp
        movl    $1, %eax        #, tmp841
        movq    %rsi, -184(%rbp)        # prephitmp.966, MEM[(struct __modulusredcul_t *)&modpp][0].invm
        cmovne  -208(%rbp), %rcx        # prephitmp.966,, %sfp, prephitmp.966
        cmovne  %rax, %r8       # cstore.863,, tmp841, cstore.863
        movq    %r8, -176(%rbp) # cstore.863, MEM[(struct __modulusredcul_t *)&modpp][0].one
```

The effect is that the result of the `ularith_div_2ul_ul_ul_r()` call is assumed to be the constant 1; the divq never appears in the output.

Various changes make the problem disappear; different compiler flags, different code context or marking the asm block `__asm__ __volatile__ (...)`. The output then correctly contains the divq instruction:

```
#APP
        # ularith_div_2ul_ul_ul_r: divq %rax %rdx %rdx -208(%rbp)       # a1, tmp590, tmp590, %sfp
        divq -208(%rbp) # %sfp
#NO_APP
```

So, my question to the inline assembly guys here: did I do something wrong with the contraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug affects only Ubuntu versions of gcc; the stock GNU gcc is unaffected as far as we can tell. The bug was reported to Ubuntu launchpad and confirmed: [Bug #1029454](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.6/+bug/1029454)